# Refresh Treenode parent to show most current child nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am able to select and expand to a particular tree node programmatically, but unable to refresh it to reflect most current data in the table. Is there Treeview1.Refresh() method ? or something like that to effect? any help will be appreciated. I have a treeview and I am adding child nodes to a parent node by having the user enter data and click on a button. After that insert into the table is done, I want the parent node to refresh and show all child entries.

```
  protected void PopulateNode(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{

    switch (e.Node.Depth)
    {
        case 0:
            PopulateChild(e.Node);
            break;

        default:
            //PopulateChild(e.Node);
            break;
    }

}

protected void PopulateChild(TreeNode node)
{

    DataSet ResultSet = RunQuery("Select Id From tbl");

    if (ResultSet.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in ResultSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
            newNode.Text = row["Id"].ToString();
            newNode.Value = row["Id"].ToString();
            newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            newNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
            node.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        }

    }

}

DataSet RunQuery(String QueryString)
{
    String ConnectionString = "asdasdasdasd";




    OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    OleDbDataAdapter DBAdapter;
    DataSet ResultsDataSet = new DataSet();

    try
    {

        DBAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(QueryString, DBConnection);
        DBAdapter.Fill(ResultsDataSet);


        DBConnection.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


        if (DBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            DBConnection.Close();
        }

    }

    return ResultsDataSet;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to reload the datatable and recreate the nodes as here http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6177

The best way to work with Treeview is with `XMLDataSource`. You can bind TreeView with it and rebind it rather than looping through rows/cols and creating each node.

Ref: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx

---

[This link](http://aspalliance.com/822) gives you and idea to convert `other datasource to XMLDataSource` and then use it to bind to treeviewl:

Once you have treeview bind to xmldatasbource, you need to refresh your datasource and then treeview with DataBind().

```
<datasource>.DataBind()
treeview1.DataBind()
```

Also, set `EnableCaching = false` for objectdatasource.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1083582/1609724.aspx

Comment: I have never used XMLdatasources before. but you definitely offer a solution to my problem. Thank you. But I want to figure out a way without having to convert or use a XMLdatasource. May be if I have no other option end of the day, I will take your solution. Thank you again , if you have any other ideas, please share with me.. really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeView` you are using has an event `SelectedNodeChanged` which is fired on whatever events are specified in the value of the `TreeNodeSelectAction` property of that `TreeNode`. In your case the value is `Expand` as I can see in your code.

When you expand a node the `SelectedNodeChanged` is fired and handled by the `PopulateNode` function as specified by the `OnSelectedNodeChanged` property that is assigned in the html.

---

What we can do here includes :

A- Collapse if already expanded then expand a tree node to repopulate its children ..

B- Change the `TreeNodeSelectAction` property value to `SelectExpand`. Here we've got one more case in which the node will be repopulated and that is node selection.

C- Call `PopulateNode` function whenever we need and assign a `TreeNode` object to its `sender` parameter and a `new TreeNodeEventArgs()` to its `e` parameter.

---

References:

[TreeNodeSelectAction Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxw0h1h7.aspx), [TreeView.TreeNodePopulate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodepopulate.aspx), [TreeNode.SelectAction Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.selectaction.aspx)